# Python: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, types

I am trying to join 2 strings using this code:

```
def __get_temp(self):
    return float(self.ask('RS'))

def __set_temp(self, temp):
    set = ('SS' + repr(temp))
    stat = self.ask(set)
    return self.check(stat)

temp = property(__get_temp, __set_temp)
```

Once together, I then send a signal over a serial bus using PyVisa. However, when I try to call the function, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
chil.temp(13)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I've tried looking around for explanation of this error, but none of them make any sense. Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: This line:

`set = ('SS' + repr(temp))`

is going to cause you pain... you're overriding a built-in type.

(Though it isn't the cause of your immediate issue.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the property temp, but what you're actually doing is *getting* the property and then trying to call it as function with the parameter 13. The syntax for setting is:

```
chil.temp = 13
```